Can we use sender.SendMessageAsync(msg) and messageActions.CompleteMessageAsync(message); within the TransactionScope?
I am having Azure function which gets Trigger when AzureService Bus Topic receives message. when my saveGuestdata success I am calling await sender.SendMessageAsync(msg); and if (Transaction.Current != null) if (Transaction.Current.TransactionInformation.Status == TransactionStatus.Active) await messageActions.CompleteMessageAsync(message); - but it is working fine for sender.SendMessageAsync and on CompleteMessageAsync getting error : Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.ServiceBusException: 'Transaction hasn't been declared yet, or has already been discharged' . here is my code: `    using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled))
{
Console.WriteLine($"Outer TransactionScope thread: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
    _logger.LogInformation("Message ID: {id}", message.MessageId);
    _logger.LogInformation("Message Body: {body}", message.Body);
    _logger.LogInformation("Message Content-Type: {contentType}", message.ContentType);

    string jsonBody = message.Body.ToString(); // If it's a string
    using var document = JsonDocument.Parse(jsonBody);
    var receivedData = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(document);
    var receivedDataJSON = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, JsonElement>>(receivedData);
    var requestKey = 0;
    var threadKey = 0;
    bool isCoreServiceActive = false;
    if (receivedDataJSON.ContainsKey("ticket"))
    {
        // Access the 'ticket' object
        _logger.LogInformation($"{receivedData}");
        var ticketsJson = JObject.Parse(receivedData)["ticket"];
        GuestRequestData guestRequestData = null;
        if (ticketsJson != null && ticketsJson.HasValues)
        {
            //var tickets = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Ticket>>(ticketsJson);
            guestRequestData = ticketsJson.ToObject<GuestRequestData>();
            if (guestRequestData.Url.Contains(zendeskUrl))
            {
                Parser.ZendeskParser parser = new ZendeskParser();
                // Task.Run(() => parser.ProcessWebhookData(guestRequestData));
                if (parser.IsGuestAndDataParseDone(guestRequestData) == true)
                {

                    HttpResponseMessage response = null;
                    var jsonPayload = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(guestRequestData);
                    Console.WriteLine("JSON Payload: " + jsonPayload);
                    var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(guestRequestData), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                    response = await httpClient.PutAsync(coreApiUrl + "/api/Threads", content);


                    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
                    {
                        // Handle the NotFound (404) case
                        _logger.LogInformation("Connector Processor: The requested Core Service resource was not found." + coreApiUrl + "/api/Threads");
                        throw new Exception("Connector Processor:  The requested Core Service resource was not found." + coreApiUrl + "/api/Threads");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                        {
                            var responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                            ThreadResponseDto threadResponseDto = new ThreadResponseDto();

                            //  apiResponseDto = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ApiResponseDto>(responseBody);

                            threadResponseDto = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ThreadResponseDto>(responseBody);
                            // ThreadResponseDto threadResponseDto = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ThreadResponseDto>(apiResponseDto.result);
                            _logger.LogInformation("Connector Processor: SaveGuestData Success Response: {responseBody}", responseBody);

                            guestRequestData.ErrorCode = "Guest Codes=" + guestRequestData.ErrorCode + "  " + threadResponseDto.Message;
                            // ThreadResponseDto threadResponseDto = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ThreadResponseDto>(apiResponseDto.Result);

                            //Add to AI queue
                            // Create a Service Bus client and sender
                            ServiceBusClientOptions options = new() { EnableCrossEntityTransactions = true };
                            await using var serviceBusClient = new ServiceBusClient(serviceBusConnectionstring, options);
                            ServiceBusSender sender = serviceBusClient.CreateSender(aiTopicName);
                            requestKey = threadResponseDto.Result.RequestKey;
                            threadKey = threadResponseDto.Result.ThreadKey;
                            string jsonString = $@"{{""thread_key"": {threadResponseDto.Result.ThreadKey}, ""request_key"": {threadResponseDto.Result.RequestKey}}}";
                            Console.WriteLine(jsonString);  // Create a message and send it to the Service Bus queue

                            ServiceBusMessage msg = new ServiceBusMessage(jsonString)
                            {
                                SessionId = threadResponseDto.Result.ThreadKey.ToString()
                            };
                            Console.WriteLine($"Outer Transaction ID: {Transaction.Current.TransactionInformation.LocalIdentifier}");
                            await sender.SendMessageAsync(msg);
                            Console.WriteLine($"Outer Transaction ID: {Transaction.Current.TransactionInformation.LocalIdentifier}");
                            _logger.LogInformation("Connector Processor:New Thread Request saved successfully to " + aiTopicName + " Queue for ThreadKey" + threadKey);

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            var responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                            ThreadResponseDto threadResponseDto = new ThreadResponseDto();
                            threadResponseDto = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ThreadResponseDto>(responseBody);

                            _logger.LogInformation("Connector Processor:SaveGuestData Failure Response: {responseBody}", responseBody);
                            guestRequestData.ErrorCode = "Guest Codes=" + guestRequestData.ErrorCode + threadResponseDto.Message;
                        }
                    }



                }//Is Guest request 
                bool Success = await CallRawDataSave(receivedData, 1, requestKey, guestRequestData.ErrorCode);


            }
            else
            {
                _logger.LogInformation(zendeskUrl + " is not found in the ticket object of the received data.");
                await CallRawDataSave(receivedData, 1, 0, zendeskUrl + " is not found ticket Object of the received JSON");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Ticket object not found in the received data.");
            await CallRawDataSave(receivedData, 1, 0, "Ticket Object not found in the received JSON");
        }
        
    }
    else
    {
        await CallRawDataSave(receivedData, 1, 0, "Ticket Object not found in the received JSON").ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
    Console.WriteLine($"Outer Transaction ID: {Transaction.Current.TransactionInformation.LocalIdentifier}");
    // Complete the message
  //  await messageActions.CompleteMessageAsync(message);
    try
    {
        if (Transaction.Current != null)
            if (Transaction.Current.TransactionInformation.Status == TransactionStatus.Active)
                   await messageActions.CompleteMessageAsync(message);
    }
    catch (ServiceBusException ex) when (ex.Reason == ServiceBusFailureReason.GeneralError)
    {
        // Log the exception and retry if necessary
        Console.WriteLine("Service Bus transaction error. Retrying...");
       // await messageActions.CompleteMessageAsync(message);
    }
    Console.WriteLine($"Outer Transaction ID: {Transaction.Current.TransactionInformation.LocalIdentifier}");
    _logger.LogInformation("Connector Processor:removed message from {topicName} topic", topicName);
    scope.Complete();
}

`
i want await sender.SendMessageAsync(msg); and messageActions.CompleteMessageAsync(message); should complete without any exception.
error log : C# ServiceBus topic trigger function processed message: {MessageId:531f51c04c4c4652b584d1c0c0bc9943}
{"thread_key": 1, "request_key": 1}
C# ServiceBus topic trigger function processed message: {MessageId:acaeda302c11463eb770e4208402048e}
{"thread_key": 1, "request_key": 1}
Connector Processor: SendMessageAsync completed
Connector Processor: SendMessageAsync completed
Connector Processor: Exception: {Message}- error log
Connector Processor: Exception: {Message}- error log
[2024-11-27T12:15:48.549Z] Executed 'Function1' (Failed, Id=85aef52d-dcd3-4389-8772-2b2c7ebcd2f1, Duration=65253ms)
[2024-11-27T12:15:48.598Z] System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Function1. System.Private.CoreLib: Input string was not in a correct format. Failure to parse near offset 33. Expected an ASCII digit.
[2024-11-27T12:15:48.825Z] Message processing error (Action=ProcessMessageCallback, EntityPath=guestrequests/Subscriptions/sub1, Endpoint=homescreendev.servicebus.windows.net)
[2024-11-27T12:15:48.827Z] System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Function1. System.Private.CoreLib: Input string was not in a correct format. Failure to parse near offset 33. Expected an ASCII digit.
[2024-11-27T12:15:48.837Z] Executed 'Function1' (Failed, Id=473336b7-bb85-4cd6-8406-cfd4b0612bde, Duration=65536ms)
[2024-11-27T12:15:48.841Z] System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Function1. System.Private.CoreLib: Input string was not in a correct format. Failure to parse near offset 33. Expected an ASCII digit.
[2024-11-27T12:15:48.845Z] Message processing error (Action=Abandon, EntityPath=guestrequests/Subscriptions/sub1, Endpoint=homescreendev.servicebus.windows.net)
[2024-11-27T12:15:48.847Z] Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus: The session lock was lost. Request a new session receiver. (SessionLockLost). For troubleshooting information, see https://aka.ms/azsdk/net/servicebus/exceptions/troubleshoot.
[2024-11-27T12:15:48.849Z] Message processing error (Action=ProcessMessageCallback, EntityPath=guestrequests/Subscriptions/sub1, Endpoint=homescreendev.servicebus.windows.net)
[2024-11-27T12:15:48.852Z] System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Function1. System.Private.CoreLib: Input string was not in a correct format. Failure to parse near offset 33. Expected an ASCII digit.
[2024-11-27T12:15:48.860Z] Message processing error (Action=Abandon, EntityPath=guestrequests/Subscriptions/sub1, Endpoint=homescreendev.servicebus.windows.net)
[2024-11-27T12:15:48.862Z] Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus: The session lock was lost. Request a new session receiver. (SessionLockLost). For troubleshooting information, see https://aka.ms/azsdk/net/servicebus/exceptions/troubleshoot.
[2024-11-27T12:15:49.315Z] Executing 'Function1' (Reason='(null)', Id=847210b2-3e07-4ae4-8cfc-fa44a45542da)
[2024-11-27T12:15:49.326Z] Trigger Details: MessageId: 531f51c04c4c4652b584d1c0c0bc9943, SequenceNumber: 940, DeliveryCount: 6, EnqueuedTimeUtc: 2024-11-27T10:07:11.9330000+00:00, LockedUntilUtc: 9999-12-31T23:59:59.9999999+00:00, SessionId: b18e6984-9f3f-4d42-b6b0-99893cdd2c76  -- for the below simplified code also the same issue -
  public class Function1
  {
      [FunctionName("Function1")]
      //public void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("%ServiceBusTopicName%", "%ServiceBusSubscriptionName%", Connection = "ServiceBusConnectionString", IsSessionsEnabled = true)]string mySbMsg, ILogger log)
     // public async Task Run([ServiceBusTrigger("%ServiceBusTopicName%", "%ServiceBusSubscriptionName%", Connection = "ServiceBusConnectionString", IsSessionsEnabled = true)]string mySbMsg, ILogger log)

        public async Task Run([ServiceBusTrigger("%ServiceBusTopicName%", "%ServiceBusSubscriptionName%", Connection = "ServiceBusConnectionString",IsSessionsEnabled =true)]
            ServiceBusReceivedMessage message,
             ServiceBusMessageActions messageActions)
      {
          string serviceBusConnectionstring = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ServiceBusConnectionString");
          string topicName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ServiceBusTopicName");
          string subscriptionName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ServiceBusSubscriptionName");
          string aiTopicName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ServiceBusAITopicName");
          string aiTopicSubscriptionName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ServiceBusAISubscriptionName");
          string zendeskUrl = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ZendeskURL");
          string userKey = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("UserKey");
          var requestKey = 1;
          var threadKey = 1;
          Console.WriteLine($"C# ServiceBus topic trigger function processed message: {message}");
          ServiceBusClientOptions options = new() { EnableCrossEntityTransactions = true };
          await using var serviceBusClient = new ServiceBusClient(serviceBusConnectionstring, options);
          ServiceBusSender sender = serviceBusClient.CreateSender(aiTopicName);

          string jsonString = $@"{{""thread_key"": {threadKey}, ""request_key"": {requestKey}}}";
          Console.WriteLine(jsonString);  // Create a message and send it to the Service Bus queue
          try
          {

              ServiceBusMessage msg = new ServiceBusMessage(jsonString)
          {
              SessionId = threadKey.ToString()
          };
          using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled))
          { 
          await sender.SendMessageAsync(msg);
          Console.WriteLine("Connector Processor: SendMessageAsync completed");
          await messageActions.CompleteMessageAsync(message);
          Console.WriteLine("Connector Processor: CompleteMessageAsync completed");
          scope.Complete();
          }
          }
          catch (Exception ex)
          {
              string errorMessage = ex.Message.ToString();
              Console.WriteLine("Connector Processor: Exception: {Message}- error log");
              Console.WriteLine("Connector Processor: Exception: {Message}", errorMessage);

              if (ex.InnerException != null)
              {
                  errorMessage += " | Inner Exception: " + ex.InnerException.Message;
              }
              Console.WriteLine("Connector Processor: Exception: {Message}", errorMessage);
              // Handle Service Bus message retries or deferral
             /* if (messageActions != null)
              {
                  try
                  {
                      // Option 1: Abandon the message so it can be retried
                      await messageActions.AbandonMessageAsync(message);
                  }
                  catch (Exception abandonEx)
                  {
                      Console.WriteLine("Connector Processor:Failed to abandon message: {Message}", abandonEx.Message);
                  }
              }*/
          }
      }
  }


Strictly speaking, whether it works or not, it is not a recommended nor supported pattern.  If you need to work with transactions, you'll want to have your application use the Azure SDK client types directly and not use the Service Bus trigger.
The pragmatic answer is "it depends."  For an in-process function, the trigger and your code share the same process, so an embedded transaction scope may work in some scenarios.  Because they exist in the same process, the trigger does see the ambient context and it becomes a timing issue.  Message actions in this scenario wrap the receiver instance directly, so if the receiver sees the transaction in the ambient context, the transaction participates in the call.
For an isolated model function, the trigger and your code are in sandboxed in different physical processes and transactions are not possible.  The trigger does not see the ambient context of your code nor the scope that you've declared.  Message actions in this scenario communicate with the Functions host via RPC channel and can only send known data between process boundaries.

thanks for your reply. kindly what let me know how to fix this for this code to work

Satated above.   In short - if you need transactions, Functions is not the right platform; you'll need to use the SDK directly.
